How to order app picker alphabetically in 24.04.01 LTS
The apps in my app picker are randomly ordered and I would like the in alphabetical order.

This question is similar to: How to order app picker alphabetically in 22.04?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

By design, the app picker contains apps in the order and placement you want to see them. There is, however, a Gnome Shell extension, Alphabetical App Grid by Stuart Hayhurst, that restores the old behavior, i.e., has the Application Overview automatically display the apps in alphabetical order.
